# What does the result of the time() function mean?

Tags: php, time

When I call the `time()` function, it returns an integer. What is the meaning of this number?

For example, running the program:

```
$time = time();
echo $time;
```

Gives the output:

```
1452082553
```

Also, how would I add a duration onto that time, for example half an hour?

Comment: This is unix timestamp from 1-Jan-1970.

Answer (score 1):

You get half an hours by,divide it by 60 to get minutes and by 60 again to get hours.

Answer (score 0):

The format is the so called `unix timestamp` which counts the seconds from January 1st of 1970 00:00 o'clock.

To calculate 1/2 hour add/subtract 30 minutes * 60 seconds = 1800.

```
$halfAnHourago = time() -1800;
```